# Angular and Typescript: proper way to reference 'this'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, controller

I am setting typescript in an angular project. In order to declare a controller I use the following syntax:

```
module app {

    class MyController {
        public myvar: boolean;

        constructor() {
            this.myvar= false;
        }
    }
    angular.module("app").controller("MainController", [MainController]);
}
```

Please note that I don't inject the scope, I only use inner properties / methods of the controller.
But I don't like to access to properties with 'this', usually I should declare:

```
var vm = this.
vm.myvar = ...
```

However this is annoying as I have many methods; I should declare this in any ones, this is repetitive.

Is there a best practice and/or a pattern, in order to declare the 'vm' only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't like to access to properties with 'this', usually I should declare `var vm = this` ... Is there a best practice and/or a pattern, in order to declare the 'vm' only once?

It's a good time to drop that practice. In TypeScript it's easy to just use `this` and not assign `this` to a variable—it's already defined for you so it's nice to use it.

The key when doing this is to use arrow functions to make sure you always use the class instance's `this` and not the `this` bound to a regular function expression.

```
class MyController {
    myVar = false;

    someOtherMethod() {
        // good
        functionWithCallback(() => {
            // this will be the class instance
            console.log(this.myVar);
        });

        // bad
        functionWithCallback(function() {
            // this will not be the class instance
            console.log(this.myVar);
        });

        // good
        functionWithCallback(() => this.myOtherMethod());

        // bad, `this` in myOtherMethod is not the class instance
        functionWithCallback(this.myOtherMethod);
    }

    myOtherMethod() {
        console.log(this.myVar);
    }
}

function functionWithCallback(callback: Function) {
    callback();
}
```